# Angular Response body returns text striped of JSON brackets. Huh?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I should preface I am new to Angular 2 a bit. I should also preface some information is internal so I will use placeholders when necessary.

I am currently trying to make a simple post request and get the contents of the request body. Here is my current code.

```
let body = {event : "makeNew"}; 
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
```

Here is the post request code:

```
this.http.post('REQUEST URL PLACEHOLDER', JSON.stringify(body) , option).map((res:Response) => res.json()).subscribe(data => {console.log(data)});
```

the console.log instead of printing normal json such as `{"id":1234, "input": "name"}` will print out text without any of the json brackets such as `1234input`.

I was wondering if I could get any input as to why this is happened. I am importing all the necessary libraries, and am not running into compile errors/ etc. I am not setting the response options to something else somewhere as well. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you checked , what data is coming from the API?

Comment: Also, in latest angular version, the `.map((res:Response) => res.json())` is not needed anymore

Comment: Yes the API works fine in PostMan and returns valid JSON.

Comment: I should also note that when I used the HttpClient implementation in Angular 4.3  I simply get null values.

Comment: The HttpClient .post and .get methods are widely used and simple to use. Maybe try removing your options. If `this.http.post(...).subscribe(data => console.log(data));` does not work, then the problem is not in Angular.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried this and again I get the same issue. I should note that I am getting a response, but its just that the response body is literally the JSON response without any brackets etc. Its just the text data without object names.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see on network tab of your browser debugger what this request is returning, maybe the problem is your server response.

Comment: I checked this and the network seems to be picking up the request. I should also note that it works fine in Postman

Comment: @user3786798 what does the raw response body look like in your network tab, though? If it looks mangled then it's your server that's the problem, not the client.

Comment: You are just doing res.json() but is not returning it...
try to chang to it:
`code .map((res:Response) => res.json())`

then in your subscribe log it

Comment: sorry for the delay in response but yes I tried this as well and get the "Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0" error. When I remove it I just get plain utf-8 text

Comment: Sorry for delay too, try it:
`code map((res:Response) => return res.json())`

If it not work, paste here the network response of your browser (f12) and the error in console tab.